# Merging changes from one context to another with Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I'm a little confused by the iOS 5 concurrency options. Usually, with the old way, you'd have to track changes from one context to another manually using mergeChanges and notifications. But if my understanding is correct, using the new options, you can have a NSMainQueueConcurrencyType with child contexts. So whenever you save on a child context, the changes are automatically pushed up and merged with the parent without any other manual work, right?

If so, I'm having a problem. Let's say I have an object that was fetched by the main context. Then I change some properties of these objects, but I don't save yet. Then, on a NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType with the parent set as the mainContext, I do a fetch to retrieve the object I just modified on the main context. Will the fetched object reflect the changes I just made to the property on the main thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will the fetched object reflect the changes I just made to the property on the main thread?

No. The changes will not be reflected in child context until you -refreshObject:mergeChanges:YES.

Just as food for thought, UIManagedDocument does this the other way around. It creates a child context for main thread and uses context with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType as parent. Now all update made on the main thread will be automatically propagated to the parent context. So when the document saves in background, all the changes will be there.

Comment: Why does this guy say that refreshObject should be used when you want to let the context know it's ok to turn the object into a fault to free up memory? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3984681/458960

Comment: You use -refreshObject:mergeChanges:NO to trim the object graph. That's you telling explicitly that you want to discard any changes that you have in your current context for the object.

Comment: Wait where do I call refreshObject? On the parent thread (where the pending change is) or on the child thread?

Comment: In your example you call it on child context after you have made changes to the parent context.